# Transaction wrap around warning

Tags: postgresql

> WARNING:  database "dbname" must be vacuumed within 5463629 transactions
>   HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a database-wide VACUUM in that database.
>   You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions.
>   VACUUM

I have run `vacuumdb --full -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres dbname`
It spits out that message galore.

I have checked active queries and there is nothing active.

It is a cluster with many DBs on Linux (postgres 9.5.10) but only this one small DB is giving this warning.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "--full".

Do you get any messages, other than the one you show, while vacuuming?

What is the output of `select datname, age(datfrozenxid) from pg_database;`

Answer (score 0):

The DB would not vacuum, dropping the DB made the wrap around vacuum start on all the other DBs and the problem is resolved.